# Github pull request history

Tags: github, pull-request

I make a PR from my fork to the upstream branch, I also merge the PR.

In this case there is only one commit in the PR. After the PR is merged and I look at the commit history of the upstream branch I see this : [image: Commit History]

Why is that? For me it looks a little confusing that there is an entry for both the commit and the PR. 
I am sure I just don't get why it is like that :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a pretty straightforward [pull request and merge](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/).

Maybe you're confusing it with a rebase. [This article](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/10/git-team-workflows-merge-or-rebase/) is quite helpful. Or is there something more to your question I'm missing?

Comment: it is just the two entries in the image ( github ). So one is the commit and one is the PR?